# Mistake in importing eps picture, cut picture

Tags: diagrams, eps

I import several eps file into my LaTeX code and after the compilation one of them seems to bu cut on the left and upper side. The rest of figures is OK. It is the fisrt time I see something simillar. In preambule of the file I do use:

```
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf},
```

and to import the file I use:

```
 \begin{figure}[!h]
    \label{fig:1}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[scale=1]{some_file.eps}
    \caption{This is some figure}
    \end{figure}
```

I will be grateful for any kind of help. Best!

Comment: it's possible that the bounding box is incorrect.  you can check that by looking at the `.eps` file with ghostview.  unfortunately, i can't easily tell you how to correct the bounding box if that is the case.

Comment: It should be possible to fix the bounding box. Near the top of the eps file, you should see something like this: `%%BoundingBox: 20 16 279 181` Change it to `%%BoundingBox: 0 0 1000 1000` or so - that is, make the box really big - save, then run through `epstopdf` and `pdfcrop`.